# Jenkins-Maven Project - Could not initialize class org.apache.tools.ant.Location

Tags: maven, ant, jenkins

I am getting an error as it is not able to initialize the ***ANT*** location although it's a Maven project.

For Jenkins job.

The output can be found below:

> [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports... [htmlpublisher] Archiving at
>   PROJECT level
>   C:\Jenkins\workspace\Capybaras-STAGE-Regression-OnDemand\target\dashboard-reports
>   to
>   /home/scmbuildmaster/.jenkins/jobs/Capybaras-STAGE-Regression-OnDemand/htmlreports/Dashboard_Full_Report_with_Screenshot FATAL: HTML Publisher failure java.io.IOException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Location     at
>   hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2213)   at
>   hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2101)   at
>   hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2084)   at
>   htmlpublisher.HtmlPublisher.perform(HtmlPublisher.java:213)   at
>   hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1784)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240) Caused by:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Location     at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:784)     at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:779)     at
>   hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:55)  at
>   hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2211)   ... 12 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Location     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectComponent.(ProjectComponent.java:43)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.types.DataType.(DataType.java:40)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.(AbstractFileSet.java:82)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet.(FileSet.java:36)   at
>   hudson.Util.createFileSet(Util.java:1077)     at
>   hudson.util.DirScanner$Glob.scan(DirScanner.java:124)     at
>   hudson.FilePath.writeToTar(FilePath.java:2249)    at
>   hudson.FilePath.access$2100(FilePath.java:191)    at
>   hudson.FilePath$45.invoke(FilePath.java:2190)     at
>   hudson.FilePath$45.invoke(FilePath.java:2186)     at
>   hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2665)  at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)     at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)   at
>   hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  at ......remote call to
>   QA-Automation-Node(Native Method)     at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1356)
>     at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:221)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:782)     ... 15 more Build
>   step 'Publish HTML reports' changed build result to FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, in the following order:

- Try to upgrade the JRE version that you use to run the slave process
- If you are using a JRE to run your slave, use a JDK If you are using
- an OpenJDK, try with an Oracle JDK